# Warning when set NSTableView datasource in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tableview

I have a sample cocoa application using `NSTableView`, 
But when I set `dataSource` for the `NSTableView`, this warning message appears:

> Sending 'AppDelegate *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nullable'

In AppDelegate.h file

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTabViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>
```

In AppDelegate.m file

```
[self.userTableView setDataSource:self];
[self.userTableView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: are you getting warning on both lines? cuz you're missing NSTableViewDelegate

Comment: Why are you using the AppDelegate as a tableView delegate?!?!?! The app delegate is there to respond to the app opening and closing... that is all. Don't use it for anything else. Especially not a tableview delegate and data source?!?

Comment: Is `NSTabViewDelegate` a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you need to confirm both protocols that you're using you've missed the `NSTableViewDelegate` in your AppDelegate.h

Comment: she wrote "NSTabViewDelegate" instead of "NSTableViewDelegate" in the AppDelegate or maybe forgot to add  NSTableViewDelegate. @shim